# extjs4 mvc event debugging inconsistent results

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4

I have a grid.Panel inside of a viewport that is binded to a store. Once the grid (or store) is loaded, I would like to look at a value in the first row (or any row), and if it's false, hide a column in the grid. I've tried many different events, but here's an example in my controller:

```
Ext.define('HelperBatchForm.controller.BatchController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
stores: [
    'Batches'
],
models: [
    'Batch'
],
views: [
    'batch.BatchGrid',
    'batch.BatchEdit'
],
init: function () {
    this.control({
        'batchgrid': {
            itemdblclick: this.editBatch                
            ,viewready: this.onGridLoad
        }
    });
},
onGridLoad: function(grid){
    stop;
},
```

"Stop" throws an error and opens the debugger in my IE browser. On the browser itself I can see the grid, and the rows, fully rendered. In the debugger, I can look at grid.store.data.items[0] and see the first row. So it seems that everything is well, and I should be able to put a condition in the function based on that data which hides the grid. But that doesn't work - here is where things start to get weird.

If I replace "stop;" with "debugger;", and reload, this time we get the visual studio debugger. But now, in the IE screen, I can only see the grid headers, and none of the data. And grid.store.data.items is an empty array. The instant I resume, I see the full grid.

But that's not all. If my function is:
    onGridLoad: function (grid) {
        alert('onGridLoad');
        debugger;
    },
Now, with the visual studio debugger loaded, I can see the full grid and data in IE. And grid.store.data.items[0] gives me the first row. If I replace "debugger" with my conditional code, it works! In other words, I have code that doesn't work, but suddenly starts working if I throw an alert() before it.

To summarize, the code below will hide the column:

```
onGridLoad: function (grid) {
    alert('onGridLoad');
    if (grid.store.findExact('is_rcm', false) >= 0) {
        grid.columns[6].hide();
    }
},
```

But if the alert is commented out, it will not hide the column.

Any ideas or explanations to why this might be would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My guess the issue here is related to async loading of the store. You are probably seeing a race condition of a split second between the view is ready but the store is not yet populated. Just like in quantum physics the observation of the event is changing its outcome :)

My suggestion is to put a load listener on the store instead and inject your processing at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I think that @dbrin is correct in assuming the data in the store is not yet loaded. But doing the processing on store load might also be problematic, when store load time is very fast, and the view is not yet ready. The following should work when the data is ready either after or before the view:

```
viewready: function(grid){
    grid.getView().on({
        refresh: {
            fn: function(){
                if (grid.store.findExact('is_rcm', false) >= 0) {
                    grid.columns[6].hide();
                }  
            },
            single: true
        }
    });
}
```

And [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amitaviv99/RBbkK/), where you can set the store load delay to test for different load times.